# Normal distribution: likelihood ratio and rejection region for estimating sigma

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I'm having a little trouble with the following problem:

"Let $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and consider testing $H_0: \sigma = \sigma_0$ versus $H_A: \sigma = \sigma_1$, where $\sigma_1 > \sigma_0$. The values $\sigma_0$ and $\sigma_1$ are fixed.

For a sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$:

(1) What is the likelihood ratio?

(2) What is the rejection region of a level $\alpha$ test?"

So far, I've gotten that the likelihood ratio is:
\begin{equation*}
\Lambda = \bigg( \frac{ \sigma_1 }  { \sigma_0 } \bigg)^n    \exp\bigg\{ \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}-\frac{1}{\sigma_0^2} \Big)   \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i^2 \bigg\}
\end{equation*}
However, the answer that I was given for the likelihood ratio doesn't have $\Big( \frac{ \sigma_1 }  { \sigma_0 } \Big)^n$, it has $\frac{ \sigma_1 }  { \sigma_0 }$. Is this a mistake in the answer?

For the rejection region, I had done the following:
\begin{equation*}
- 2 \log(\Lambda) = - 2 n \log\bigg( \frac{ \sigma_1 }  { \sigma_0 } \bigg)    + \Big(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}-\frac{1}{\sigma_0^2} \Big)   \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i^2 
\end{equation*}

Since $-2\log(\lambda) \sim \chi^2_1$, we see that
                \begin{equation*}
     - 2 n \log\bigg( \frac{ \sigma_1 }  { \sigma_0 } \bigg)    + \Big(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}-\frac{1}{\sigma_0^2} \Big)   \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i^2 > \chi^2_1(\alpha)
    \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
         \bigg| \frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}-\frac{1}{\sigma_0^2} \bigg|     \geq     \frac{2z(\alpha/2) + 4 n \log(\sigma_1/\sigma_0) } {x^2}
    \end{equation*}

This rejection region doesn't seem right to me though. Could someone explain to me where I went wrong?

Comment: You've got an extra factor of $\dfrac 1 2$ inside the exponential. $\qquad$

Comment: Right, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: When you write \text{exp} or \text{log}, instead of \exp and \log, you don't automatically get proper spacing.  Consider what you get from A\exp B and A\exp(B) and A\text{exp} B and $A\text{exp}(B)$: $$A\exp B$$ $$A\exp(B)$$ $$A\text{exp} B$$ $$A\text{exp}(B)$$  The second one has less space to the right of $\exp$ than the first one; that's built in to the software; the last two lack proper spacing. $\qquad$

Comment: I wasn't aware of the spacing difference, but that is good to know. Thank you for writing that out

Comment: Typo: That fourth one was A\text{exp} B. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that there should be an $n$th power.

You reject the null hypothesis if $\Lambda$ is too small (since the density under the null hypothesis is in the numerator.  That happens if
$$
\left( \frac 1 {\sigma_1^2} - \frac 1 {\sigma_0^2} \right) \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2
$$
is too small.  If $\sigma_1>\sigma_0$, that happens if $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ is too big.  If $\sigma_1<\sigma_0$, it happens if that sum is too small.

Under the null hypothesis you have $\displaystyle \frac 1 {\sigma_0^2} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \sim \chi^2_n$.

Suppose we let $\chi_n^2(\alpha)$ the the positive number satisfying $\Pr(\chi_n^2 > \chi_n^2(\alpha)) = \alpha$.  If we reject the null hypothesis when our sum of squares is too big, then we reject the null hypothesis if that sum is bigger than $\sigma_0^2 \chi_n^2(\alpha)$.  The rejection region is then the interval $(\sigma^2 \chi_n^2(\alpha),\infty)$.

If the opposite inequality on the two hypothetical variances holds, then mutatis mutandis.

Comment: Is the rejection region supposed to be $\sigma_0^2 \chi^2_n(\alpha)$? I'm confused by what $\sigma^2_n(\alpha)$ means

Comment: Also, would you mind elaborating on how you got the null distribution? I'm confused about where the $1/\sigma_1^2$ term went

Comment: @cooperl1 : Sorry -- I meant $\sigma^2 \chi_n^2(\alpha)$, with $\chi_n^2(\alpha)$ defined as above. $\qquad$